# dotCover in FAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Currently I'm migrating TeamCity build steps to FAKE and now I'm stuck on running tests with dotCover.

Could you provide an example how to properly use [DotCover](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-dotcover.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found an answer to my question:

```
!! (buildDir @@ buildMode @@ "/*.Unit.Tests.dll") 
|> DotCoverNUnit 
    (fun dotCoverOptions -> { dotCoverOptions with 
            Output = artifactsDir @@ "NUnitDotCover.snapshot" }) 
    (fun nUnitOptions -> { nUnitOptions with
            DisableShadowCopy = true })
```